# Comparing two Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dictionary, comparison

I have two dictionaries, both with the same structure and order (one is supposed to be an exact replicate of the other): `Dictionary<int, ICustomInterface>`and I want to check that they are equal using `SequenceEqual<>`

First, I turn the first dictionary into XML, and then read it back to recreate the second one. Upon initial inspection, they are both the same. The `ICustomeInterface` objects each override the Equals method properly. To check this, I iterate over the elements of the two dictionaries and compare them. They are all equal.

But when I call the `SequenceEqual`:`dictionary1.SequenceEqual(dictionary2);` it returns false and the Equals methods of the `ICustomInterface` objects never get called and it always returns false. However, if I do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < firstDictionary.Count; i++)
   firstDictionary[i].SequenceEqual(otherSub.ItemSequence[i]);
```

everything works as expected and it returns true for every line. So, what's going on when I simply call SequnceEqual on the dictionary itself?

Comment: "The ICustomeInterface objects each override the Equals method properly." Does that include a consistent override for `GetHashCode()`? Not sure if it's relevant here, but a broken `GetHashCode()` is one of the most common problems with equality comparisons.

Comment: What's the underlying type? Is it a value type or a reference type?

Comment: You have a contradiction in your post. You state you have " two ordered Dictionaries" but on the other hand you state that you use `Dictionary<int, ICustomInterface>`, which is unordered.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I meant that their elements were in the same order. Hopefully I fixed the misunderstanding in the edit

Comment: Then your problem is the misunderstanding that elements in a dictionary *have* a well defined order in the first place.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"What's going on" is it's comparing `KeyValuePair` entries for the two dictionaries, in order. Dictionaries are inherently unordered - you shouldn't be relying on anything about the order in which entries come out of them. If you use:

```
firstDictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
               .SequenceEqual(secondDictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key))
```

I suspect you'll find that matches. It's a pretty unpleasant way to compare them though :)

Comment: Couldn't one implement an IEqualityComparer so the comparison isn't just a reference comparison

Comment: @Conrad: Yes, you could... but then you immediately run into the problem of ordering, so it doesn't help much.

Comment: @JonSkeet KeyValuePair is a ValueType, so Equals works as expected. Although, if it contains reference types, it will be slow since it uses reflection. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx). The problem of ordering still remains though.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet has already given a good explanation.

However if all you (or anyone else reading this question) want is an efficient method of comparing dictionaries here is a simple Linq-based extension that will do just that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Compares two dictionaries for equality.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// True if the dictionaries have equal contents or are both null, otherwise false.
/// </returns>
public static bool DictionaryEqual<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict1, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict2,
    IEqualityComparer<TValue> equalityComparer = null)
{
    if (dict1 == dict2)
        return true;

    if (dict1 == null | dict2 == null)
        return false;

    if (dict1.Count != dict2.Count)
        return false;

    if (equalityComparer == null)
        equalityComparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;

    return dict1.All(kvp =>
        {
            TValue value2;
            return dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value2)
                && equalityComparer.Equals(kvp.Value, value2);
        });
}
```

It does perhaps look a bit fluffy, but I wanted good readability (and null tests).

**So if all you want is a "one-liner"** and you already know that both dictionaries are non-null and that the `TValue` type overrides the Equals method properly, then you only really need this much (sans the null-checks if `TValue` is a valuetype of course):

```
bool isEqual = dict1.Count == dict2.Count && dict1.All(kvp =>
    {
        TValue value2;
        return dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value2)
            && (kvp.Value == null ? value2 == null : kvp.Value.Equals(value2));
    });
```

---

If you want to do a compare where the dictionaries doesn't have to have the same type of value, or if you prefer to use a delegate or lambda expression instead of having to implement an IEqualityComparer, this extension will do the trick for you instead:

```
/// <summary>
/// Compares two dictionaries for equality using a custom value equality function.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// True if both dictionaries are null or both have the same set of keys and comparing
/// their respective values for each key using the <paramref name="valueEqualityFunc"/>
/// returns true, otherwise false.
/// </returns>
public static bool DictionaryEqual<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dict1, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> dict2,
    Func<TValue1, TValue2, bool> valueEqualityFunc)
{
    if (valueEqualityFunc == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("valueEqualityFunc");

    if (dict1 == dict2)
        return true;

    if (dict1 == null | dict2 == null)
        return false;

    if (dict1.Count != dict2.Count)
        return false;

    return dict1.All(kvp =>
    {
        TValue2 value2;
        return dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value2)
            && valueEqualityFunc(kvp.Value, value2);
    });
}
```

As you can see it's pretty much the same thing as before.

Here is a usage example:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

d1.Add("key1", "dog");
d2.Add("key1", "Dog");
d1.Add("key2", "CAT");
d2.Add("key2", "cat");

bool isEqual = DictionaryEqual(d1, d2,
    (s1, s2) => string.Equals(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

If you run the above code `isEqual` will become true.

---

**Caution:**
As user LukeSchoen points out in the comments, this method might fail to give the expected result if the dictionaries being tested don't use the same EqualityComparer for comparing keys *(remember that you can optionally specify an equality comparer for your keys in the dictionary constructor, e.g. to use case-insensitive string keys)*.

This cannot be fixed since one cannot generalize what's "expected" from trying to equate two dictionaries that use different definitions of equality.

The only solution in the general case is to let the caller specify their own EqaulityComparer for the inter-dictionary key comparison, similarly to how the code above lets the caller specify how values are compared, thus making it the callers responsibility to provide a sensible definition of equality for their use case.

Comment: This implementation has a bug. You need to compare in both directions or this comparison be incorrect: firstDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Key", "Value" },
                { "key", "Value" }
            };   var secondDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            {
                { "key", "Value" },
                { "notakey", "NotAValue" }
            };

Comment: So in summary you need

            bool forward = dict1.All(kvp => dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out TValue value2) && equalityComparer.Equals(kvp.Value, value2));
            bool reverse = dict2.All(kvp => dict1.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out TValue value2) && equalityComparer.Equals(kvp.Value, value2));
            return forward && reverse;

Comment: @LukeSchoen I'm not sure I see your point. Are you saying that if one dict ignores key case and the other doesn't there will be a problem? In that case your comment is missing the point: we allow the caller to supplying a value-comparer so that the we don't need to assume what "equals" means for the values. I do however assume that key equality is ordinal. And if you don't want that assumption then the proper solution is to rewrite the method to accept a key-comparer argument too.

Comment: @LukeSchoen Your code doesn't really address the issue. Lets say you add "notakey", "NotAValue" to your first dict so it has 3 values in total, then by your reasoning / code they are equal, even though one of them has 3 entries and the other one only has 2 entries. That is some really non-obvious assumption and not really an improvement - it's not "more correct" just different.

Comment: The point is that an odd corner case of a case insensitive dictionary could induce the original code to return that two obviously unequal dictionaries are equal. Your example of one dictionary having 3 kvps and and the other having 2 is covered by your original code which checks dict.count.

Comment: @LukeSchoen You are correct in that sense, but your code doesn't solve the problem nicely. I really think the only solution is to not use TryGetValue and get everything as KVP class instances on which you compare the keys "yourself" hence ignoring the key-equality-comparer set for any of the dictionaries. Comparing two dictionaries which uses different eqaulity-comparers and thus have different definitions of equality doesn't make any logical sense after all. But it's good that you warn others of the potential pitfall that arises from custom set key equality comparers. +1